# Change Host Header in rewrite rule IIS

Tags: c#, .net, curl, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="myTest_rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(contacto.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www)\.(myfirstsite)\.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://abc.mysfirstsite.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true />
</rule>
```

#### Questions

1. When the request rewrites from `www.myfirstsite.com` to `abc.mysfirstsite.com`, what would be the host header when request rewrites to `abc.mysfirstsite.com`? Will it be `abc.mysfirstsite.com` or `www.myfirstsite.com`?
2. If the host header in above question is `abc.mysfirstsite.com`, then how do I change it to `www.myfirstsite.com` through my rewrite rule ?

Comment: Please refer this  [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723709/change-host-header-with-iis-urlrewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example in setting up HTTP request headers and IIS server variables

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>URL Rewrite Module v2 Test - Setting Server Variables</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Setting HTTP request header and a server variable with URL Rewrite Module v2</h1>
 <p>The value of the Language cookie is <strong><%=( Request.Cookies["Language"] != null ) ? Request.Cookies["Language"].Value : "Cookie not set" %></strong></p>
 <p>The originally requested URI is <strong><%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode( Request.ServerVariables["ORIGINAL_URI"] ) %></strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables) with complete information about creating rewrite rule in HTTP headers. and also you can refer the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727190/15969833) with related information.